# How can we run browser in the background and foreground?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, sikuli

I am trying to automate one process. For which , I am taking user input from user in between of the process. I am using sikuli to automate the autheticate login pop up.

Because I am using Sikuli so i want to put browser on the foreground so that sikuli can work perfectly. But after sikuli finished its work,I want that browser to be run in the background or below the eclipse or terminal on which I am taking user input.

I tried robot with which I am minimizing the browser after sikuli work. It is minimizing the browser But after taking user input i need to put the browser on the front again. For that i used:
1.) driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl()) - not working
2.) driver.manage().window().maximize() -not working

So please suggest me some way to do this process.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to use `driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle())`...

Comment: no, its not working. After minimizing the browser , I used your command to put browser in the foreground but it is not working. I think that this error occur because script is minimizing the browser. DO you know any method with which instead of minimizing , browser will run at the back of all apps or eclipse application.

Comment: Please refer to the below link.
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/how-to-switch-handle-particular-popup-window-when-multiple-popup-are-opened-an

Answer (score 0):

Authenticare login popup is htaccess popup ? Then you can go with `http://username:password@yoururl` to bypass the authentication.

Comment: I used that. I don't have any issue with login pop up. Your method will work in the start only . Actually I am getting pop up on many page after loading of url and clicking on elements. So with this , I am not getting first pop up.

Comment: If its Windows popup then `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` or `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();` should work. Please try with that.

Comment: Actually I did not ask question related to pop up. Please read the question . I asked how can i run the browser in the background.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding your question, you are using sikuli to handel browser authentication and after that also you have many popup windows and you want to enter some user inputs. That you want to do via eclipse/terminal. Please correct if I am wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

[Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) may be what you're looking for

Comment: no , i am not looking for phantomJS. I just want to put browser under some application.

Comment: With phantoms, the "browser" will always be under any application that is open

Comment: Actually PhantomJS is headless browser . It is not visible to user. I can just take screenshot of every step . And check that one. But Browser can't run under any application with PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for `App.focus()`? 
With that you can pull certain applications to the foreground. 
For example: 
App.focus('Firefox')